# Node js SSL error {"code":"CERT_UNTRUSTED"}

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I am using node version 0.12.7 with  npm (2.11.3) and sails (0.11.5).
So in the project i consuming REST Api using request (npm Module). 
API is on another domain so I enable CORS in sails, Everything is working fine On QA server but
when i move my code to production (API is hosted with SSL) at API call it says

```
{"code":"CERT_UNTRUSTED"}.
```

Below is API call with request module.

```
request({
        url: sails.config.constant.baseApiUrl+'login',
        method: "POST",
        json: true, 
        body: data
    }, function (error, response, body){
            console.log('error:- '+JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('response:- '+JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log('body:- '+JSON.stringify(body));


         // Other code to handle response

    });


****Response:-**** 
error:- {"code":"CERT_UNTRUSTED"}
response:- undefined
body:- undefined
```

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like the server hosting your api has an invalid cert. Was it self-signed?

Comment: No. Certificate is issued from   trusted third party. API is working fine, I tested with iphone app. Problem with only web when it consume REST Api